# Correct way to take a subset of a dataset?

Tags: dataset, sampling, binary-classification, weka

I am attempting a binary classification problem (using Weka). My dataset has 100,000 rows, 14 attributes (1 output variable). It takes already too long just to open the dataset in excel so I just know my laptop won't be able to run all that data through supervised learning algorithms in a reasonable time. What is the correct way to take a subset of a dataset?

Say I want to try build a Logistic Regression model on 1000 rows only? Do I need to carefully preserve the "information" contained in the 100,000 rows or can I cherry pick whatever 1000 rows I want? For instance in the full dataset the ratio in the output variable is: Y=20%, N=80%. When I tried just taking the first 1000 rows from my excel file the ratio in the output variable became: Y=18%, N=82%. Either way that is unbalanced which is bad apparently.

Can I choose 1000 rows such that I have an even split of data in the output variable or will that end up making a less accurate model and maybe bad practice? Likewise I have a "Gender" attribute (male vs female). Is it ok to engineer a subset of the 100,000 dataset (for training) that has an equal split of gender even if though the original 100,000 dataset is 65% female, 35% male?

As you can see I don't really understand the basics. I want to take a subset of a large dataset but I'm not sure what you are allowed to do because maybe you cherry pick things then your training dataset is not longer representative of the original dataset.

Comment: Hi, I think 100k rows is not such a big number, you probably do not even need to sample your data.

Comment: If you want to do ML, I would recommend you to make yourself familiar with Python and it's DS/ML libraries pandas and scikit-learn. With both you can do sampling. Python with pandas can handle files for the size you mention easily. But I think that also Weka has methods to sample. It might be important that your target variable is respected in the sampling (in the sense of statified sampling), because otherwise you could shift the distribution and with that also the results of your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to carefully preserve the information contained in the 100,000 rows or can I cherry pick whatever 1000 rows I want?

The concern about Class Imbalance you're expressing is: "Will my
model succeed at **generalizing** to unseen examples if I train on skewed data?"

Usually the answer is "yes!", but you should try it and see,
as it can depend upon details of the data.

There is a danger that a simple classifier model based on
[LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) or
[OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)
can learn to (almost) always vote for the majority class.
Which is why we usually care more about
[precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score#Definition)
and recall than about
[accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox).
Bagging and
[boosting](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost)
are effective techniques for coping with imbalance.

---

You didn't describe your dataset as being a timeseries.
So let's produce a random shuffle of the rows and use that as our input.

Train LR model M1 on the first thousand rows,
and LR model M2 on the next thousand rows, that is, on the next
[fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation).

Hopefully we see that the two models have learned similar parameters,
and exhibit similar behavior when validated against subsequent folds.
(If not, well, you have some diagnostic effort ahead of you.)
Write down these
[out-of-sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets#Validation_data_set)
F1 scores.

Now draw a
[**balanced**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis)
fold comprised of 500 `Y` and 500 `N` examples.
Use it to train LR model M3.
Produce another balanced fold and train model M4.
Score them against unseen validation folds as before.

Likely models {M3, M4} have F1 performance
better than the {M1, M2} scores.
If so, then prefer balanced training folds when you produce LR models,
as that works better for your dataset.

Comment: Thank you! In my 110,000 row dataset the output variable has 88k=No and 22k=yes. I have to use Weka for this project. I discovered the `SpreadSubsample` and `SMOTE` filters to under and over-sample the dataset to balance the o/p variable. I read that a combination of over and under sampling is better than either alone. Problem is when I use SMOTE Weka keeps crashing cos I run out of memory. I tried increasing but still 8GB not enough and don't think I have enough more on my laptop. I have no choice but to only use under-sampling it seems.